# Entity framework 6 not updating foreign key relation

Tags: wpf, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hello I have a strange issue here. I have a `Project` model that has a foreign key to the `Company` model. The thing is that when I attach my `Project` property in order to update it, then it updates all other primitive fields, except for the Company.

The `Project` model looks like this:

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }

    public bool ExportProjectName { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Then what I do, is I have a `ProjectsViewModel`, that gets all Projects from the Database. I wrap each of them then in a `ProjectViewModel` which exposes some fields of the `Project` and also has a saving method. I think the `ProjectsViewModel` implementation may not be that important so I'll paste only the two lines that populate the `ProjectViewModel`s:

```
var projects = dbcontext.Projects.Include(x => x.Company).ToList().Select(x => new ProjectViewModel(x));
this.ListOfProjects = new ObservableCollection<ProjectViewModel>(projects);
```

Then I have the `ProjectViewModel`. Take a look at the `SaveProject` method:

```
public class ProjectViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Project _project;

    public Project Project
    {
        get { return _project; }
        set
        {
            _project = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Project");
        }
    }

    public int ID
    {
        get { return Project.ID; }
        set
        {
            Project.ID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ID");
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return Project.Name; }
        set
        {
            Project.Name = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


    public Company Company
    {
        get { return Project.Company; }
        set
        {
            Project.Company = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Company");
        }
    }

    public ProjectViewModel(Project project)
    {
        this.Project = project;
    }

    public void SaveProject()
    {
        using (DbContext dbcontext = new DbContext())
        {
            // At this state this.Project and this.Company exist in the database
            dbcontext.Companies.Attach(this.Company);
            dbcontext.Projects.Attach(this.Project);
            dbcontext.Entry(this.Project).State = EntityState.Modified;
            dbcontext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

And that's it. I have the `SaveProject` bound to a command, which I just trigger.

And then in the logs I can only see such a query:

```
Opened connection at 08/12/2018 17:47:21 +01:00

Started transaction at 08/12/2018 17:47:21 +01:00

UPDATE "public"."Projects" SET "Name"=@p_0,"ExportProjectName"=@p_1,"CreatedAt"=@p_2 WHERE "ID" = @p_3
```

So all properties are there, except for the Company. If that's important - I'm using PostgreSQL with NpgSql. I saw many question on SO in regards to the related object not being updated itself, but I couldn't find any question where the relation would be only broken. Hope somebody can help!

EDIT:
BTW the code below would work, but I do not want to assign all properties by myself and would want to avoid getting the object from the DB one more time. And I want to know, why the relation is not updated in the first case, as it doesn't make sense for me.

```
dbcontext.Companies.Attach(this.Company);
var p = dbcontext.Projects.Single(x => x.ID == this.ID);
p.Name = this.Name;
p.Company = this.Company;
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I think you need companyid or whatever the fk is in your project class.

Comment: Could you elaborate or paste an example what exactly you mean?

Comment: In your database you presumably have the foreign key for company on project. That needs to change or nothing will happen. Add a corresponding public int property to your project class and set that when you change the associated company.

Comment: Setting an entity's state to `Modified` only marks scalar properties as changed. So yes, add CompanyId.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation guys! So you mean to change the Project model itself? I do not fully like this idea. Why would I want to have redundant data in 2 separate model fields (Company and CompanyID)? Is there no way to mark a Reference as modified? When EF6 gets and object from the DB it somehow manages to update the relation, so I believe there should be a way to do that also when attaching, without the need to query for the Project object from the DB.